# C++ linked binary search tree (DeleteTree)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, new-operator, delete-operator

I have to implement a binary search tree using C++ for one of assignments. I've created the class, and attempted to implement the **InsertItem, PrintTree, DeleteTree** methods for the class, I think I did everything right but for some reason my program keeps crashing :(

Here's my code:

**PrintTree Method**

```
template <class TItem>
void BinarySearchTree<TItem>::PrintTree()
{
    PrintTree(RootNode);
}

template <class TItem>
void BinarySearchTree<TItem>::PrintTree(BinarySearchTreeNode* Node)
{
    if(Node == NULL)
        return;

    cout << Node->Data << endl;
    PrintTree(Node->LeftChild);
    PrintTree(Node->RightChild);
}
```

**DeleteTree Method**

```
template <class TItem>
void BinarySearchTree<TItem>::DeleteTree()
{
    DeleteTree(RootNode);
}

template <class TItem>
void BinarySearchTree<TItem>::DeleteTree(BinarySearchTreeNode* Node)
{
    if(Node == NULL)
        return;

    DeleteTree(Node->LeftChild);
    DeleteTree(Node->RightChild);

    delete Node;
}
```

**My sequence of method calls up until the program crashes:**

I insert items `F,B,G,A,D,I,C,E,H`: **works fine**

I call `PrintTree()`: **works fine**

I call `DeleteTree()`: **works fine**

I call `PrintTree()` again: **program crashes**

For some reason the expression `if(RootNode == NULL)` is not returning true after the `DeleteTree()` method is called, so the program tries to print something that doesn't exist and crashes. I'm not sure why this is happening, what am I doing wrong here?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: this seems to be a dangling pointer : calling `delete p ;` on a pointer does not set it to 0. So in the end the memory pointed by `RootNode` is freed by the last call to `delete Node ;`. You should add `RootNode = 0 ;` in the end of `::DeleteTree()`

Comment: @totem - this solves the problem for the `DeleteTree()` method, but not if you pass in a specific node that isn't `RootNode` to `DeleteTree(*Node)`

Comment: @BrianRoach indeed, the _best change_ (although not clean imo) with the provided code would be to pass the pointer as a `Node**`. But it's ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling "delete" does not null out the pointer. 
You will want to do:

```
delete Node; 
Node = nullptr;
```

EDIT:

Pass the pointer by address so that you can clean up dangling pointers as you go:

```
void BinarySearchTree<TItem>::DeleteTree(BinarySearchTreeNode *&node);
```

Comment: Or `Node = NULL;` if you don't have C++11.

Comment: No, you don't, since that wouldn't do anything outside the method ;) (That would require a pointer to a pointer)

Comment: @SethCarnegie Ah yes, good point. I am pretty sure the common compilers support this as of the C++0x working draft. Either way, to be consistent with your other code NULL would probably be better.

Comment: @Nasgul You should also take the pointer by reference, so the function should accept a `BinarySearchTreeNode*& Node`. This way it will change the pointer in the tree, not just the local variable.

Comment: Hey, I already tried `Node = NULL` and I've just tried 'Node = nullptr;` as well, neither seemed to work. Nasgul is right, that isn't the problem. I've solved it with totem's suggestion but I was hoping for something where I wouldn't have to use `RootNode` itself.

Comment: @SaadImran. Like I said, you have to take the pointer by reference, so the function should accept a BinarySearchTreeNode*& Node. This way it will change the pointer in the tree, not just the local variable when you do `Node = NULL;`

Comment: @SethCarnegie Ah you beat me to it Seth. I missed the pass by reference in my initial answer.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Yes, I was trying that out right now. Taking a reference pointer as the parameter solved the problem for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the delete function should be changed to the following,

```
template <class TItem>
void BinarySearchTree<TItem>::DeleteTree(BinarySearchTreeNode** Node)
{
    if((*Node) == NULL)
        return;

    DeleteTree(&(*Node)->LeftChild);
    DeleteTree(&(*Node)->RightChild);

    delete (*Node);
    (*Node) = NULL;
}
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This works, so I will upvote, but I will accept the other solution just because it's a little bit cleaner for my taste. Thanks though, appreciate the help.

Comment: This is still wrong because it doesn't set `*Node` to `NULL`, and also because `(*Node)->LeftChild` and `->RightChild` aren't `BinarySearchTreeNode**`s (they're only `BinarySearchTreeNode*`s). You'll have to pass the address of `RightChild` and `LeftChild`. I think fixing those things should fix this though.